# php returns empty variables on ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I am trying to get the hang of php and ajax post.  I am posting simple user input via text box to a php page. The php page takes the user input, counts words and sends it back as response.  However it can't receive the data, comes back saying. Why is this how do I fix it?

This is my jQuery ajax post code

```
var dataString = name;
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test_get.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

This is my PHP code

```
// if data are received via POST, with index of 'dataString'
if (isset($_POST['dataString'])) {
    $str = $_POST['dataString'];             // get data
    echo "The string: '<i>".$str."</i>' contains ". strlen($str). ' characters and '. str_word_count($str, 0). ' words.';
}

else echo 'There is no data!';
```

Comment: Have you used FireBug to verify your POST and it's return?

Comment: Please install some debug tools like firebug so you can always debug it by yourself (you can read the ajax request and response), it's really useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to change:

```
data: dataString,
```

To

```
data: "dataString="+dataString,
```

Because a HTTP POST still runs off of key/value pairs.

Comment: @user2002077: You should consider using an object as per my answer as it is much more easily expanded and less prone to typographical errors than manually typing out query strings.

Comment: I agree with using an object with multiple values, but for a single value there is little benefit. In all cases it gets converted straight back into a string.

Answer (score 6):

Your `data` argument is incorrect.

```
var dataString = name;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test_get.php",
  data: {"dataString" : dataString },
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
   }
});
```

[Read the jQuery $.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.